# EF Core map columns to a collection of objects

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I've got a legacy database that contains annual data in the following format (simplified):

```
CategoryId | CategoryName | CountryId | CountryName | Offset | Year0 | Year1 | Year2 | Year3 | Year4 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
         1 | Potatoes     |         2 | Latvia      |   2001 |   123 |   123 |   123 |   123 |   123 |
```

As you can see, this is time series data which stores data for 5 years. Based on `Offset` column, `Year[0-4]` column will represent different year.

So in this case this can be read as:

```
CategoryId | CategoryName | CountryId | CountryName | 2001 | 2002 | 2003 | 2004 | 2005 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
         1 | Potatoes     |         2 | Latvia      |  123 |  123 |  123 |  123 |  123 |
```

If `Offset` changes, column *meaning* changes as well.

I'll be working on writing a service which will have to use this database and I'd like to map these results to this kind of structure:

```
public class Category
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Country
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Datum
{
    public int Year { get; set; }

    public decimal Sales { get; set; }
}

public class Experiment
{
    public Category Category { get; set; }

    public Country Country { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Datum> Datum { get; set; }
}
```

Year columns should be mapped to `IEnumerable<Datum>` and then the whole object could be represented as follows:

```
new Experiment
{
    Category = new Category { Id = 1, Name = "Potatoes" },
    Country = new Country { Id = 2, Name = "Latvia" },
    Datum = new List<Datum>
    {
        new Datum { Year = 2001, Sales = 123 },
        new Datum { Year = 2002, Sales = 123 },
        new Datum { Year = 2002, Sales = 123 },
        new Datum { Year = 2003, Sales = 123 },
        new Datum { Year = 2004, Sales = 123 }
    }
};
```

How could I do that using EF Core?

Requested update. This wouldn't be difficult with Linq as suggested in comments, but I was wondering whether I could incorporate this mapping to EF Core.

```
class MainClass
{
    public static IEnumerable<DatabaseRow> rows = new List<DatabaseRow>
    {
        new DatabaseRow
        {
            CategoryId = 1,
            CategoryName = "Potatoes",
            CountryId = 2,
            CountryName = "Latvia",
            Offset = 2001,
            Year0 = 123,
            Year1 = 123,
            Year2 = 123,
            Year3 = 123,
            Year4 = 123
        }
    };

    public static void Main (string[] args)
    {
        var transformed = rows.Select(row => new Experiment
        {
            Category = new Category
            {
                Id = row.CategoryId,
                Name = row.CategoryName
            },
            Country = new Country
            {
                Id = row.CountryId,
                Name = row.CountryName
            },
            Datum = new List<Datum>
            {
                new Datum
                {
                  Year = row.Offset,
                  Sales = row.Year0
                },
                new Datum
                {
                  Year = row.Offset + 1,
                  Sales = row.Year1
                },
                new Datum
                {
                  Year = row.Offset + 2,
                  Sales = row.Year2
                },
                new Datum
                {
                  Year = row.Offset + 3,
                  Sales = row.Year3
                },
                new Datum
                {
                  Year = row.Offset + 4,
                  Sales = row.Year4
                }
            }
        });
    }
}

class DatabaseRow
{
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }

    public int CountryId { get; set; }
    public string CountryName { get; set; }

    public int Offset { get; set; }
    public decimal Year0 { get; set; }
    public decimal Year1 { get; set; }
    public decimal Year2 { get; set; }
    public decimal Year3 { get; set; }
    public decimal Year4 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I think this is a linq question instead of ef core. Also, what have you tried so far?

Comment: @PaoloGo I've had in mind that it's doable with Linq, updated question with a possible solution. I could totally have this code in repository, but I'd prefer to avoid it if possible.

Comment: @EvaldasBuinauskas You could use a DTO, but I'm assuming you want EF to do this, if thats the case. Just do the mapping to the list in the constuctor

Comment: I would prefer to use EF but if that's difficult and unreasonable, I'd rather put it aside.